Failed to resolve module specifier "@tauri-apps/api/http"
import { fetch } from '@tauri-apps/api/http';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
  const serverIP = 'http://185.221.21.49:30120/players.json';
  const playerCountElement = document.getElementById('player-count');

const response = await fetch(serverIP, {   method: 'GET', timeout: 1000, })
console.log("response:", response)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
      return response.data;
    })
    .then(data => {
      if (data && data.players) {
        playerCountElement.textContent = `Játékosok száma: ${data.players.length}`;
      } else {
        playerCountElement.textContent = "Játékosok száma: Nem sikerült lekérni";
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error fetching player count:", error);
      playerCountElement.textContent = "Játékosok száma: Nem sikerült lekérni";
    });
});


This results in

Error code: TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@tauri-apps/api/http". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".


I've tried everything, I've searched and searched for a solution but I can't find it, please help me. I just can't get it to work.
I've tried a lot of things, most of which I've saturated by search

It is unclear what your problem really is ,
But on close inspection my guts tell me that, you may be missing some security setting , check your csp settings and your http allow list .
Also check your permissions settings in your capabilities/base.json
something like this may be missing
{
  "permissions": [
    {
      "identifier": "http:default",
      "allow": [{ "url": "https://*.tauri.app" }],
      "deny": [{ "url": "https://private.tauri.app" }]
    }
  ]
}

I cannot tell exactly what the problem is as you have given very little information , but it is most likely a security or permissions issue.
And I can tell from experience ,considering the context of the error code .
